# Question about OSGi for embedded

Tags: java-me

I am going to work on the OSGi-based Embedded/Mobile applications. I have some confused questions need to be clarified.

(1) Can Equinox run on J2ME environment or not?

(2) How to start the Equinox OSGi container under the pure J2ME environment (not JDK and JRE installed)?

(3) Can I use some external jars / Third party's jars (which is based on JRE classes) for the embedded application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Java ME is something of an "embedded" environment, meaning amongst other things that there is generally not as much memory to run in or storage space.  At one time there were application size limits.

What this means is that instead of trying to dump big, fat, J2SE jars into a device with limited capabilities, perhaps you should try rethinking what you are trying to accomplish.

Also consider that the version of Java that mobile phones run is fairly limited, so many 'regular' Java applications and libraries will not work there.

You can include jars in your applications, by taking their contents and dumping them in the jar you create.

In other words, you have to think differently about Java ME - it's not the bloated world that most Java stuff inhabits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Equinox OSGi but, as I found from it's [web page](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/), it's looks like support [OSGi MEG](http://www.osgi.org/MEG/HomePage). Then it could run on mobile devices with Java ME CDC runtime not CLDC.
OSGi should depends on features of CDC VM as like dynamic class loading, refelection or else.

Please find phoneME CDC project (phoneME advanced) from [here](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/downloads_page.html).